# Curl and Data read from Terminal in Python

Tags: python, request

I would like to use python to read data from a webpage by using request library. When i use

```
curl 'https://www.garantimortgage.com/apps/Socket/Webservice.ashx' --data 'cityId=3969&cmd=districts'
```

Works perfect on terminal. Is there any way to get this data by using python with request or any other library?

Comment: Yes. Have you looked at requests’s documentation?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i did. But what i want is not to get value from terminal. It is to get value from a web page. I wanted to show the result by posting terminal code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to dump to the terminal, but:

1. Create / send request in python
   create a string of your url and data - send - read

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

2. use os.system to make a 'curl' request from the command line, and pipe the output

[How To Capture Output of Curl from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158701/how-to-capture-output-of-curl-from-python-script)